# How can I apply an effect to an address for a set time?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I am using a dividend pool system for my token. Currently, when a user withdraws their dividends they have this line of code is run:

```
    emit Transfer(address(this), msg.sender, DividendstoDividend);
emit Transfer(address(this), address(0), DividendsToBurn);
_SavedDividend[msg.sender] = 0;
RestrictedFromDividend[msg.sender] = true;
```

Is there some sort of way I can make it so that the "RestrictedFromDividend" mapping only lasts for a certain period of time, and then have it switch back to false?

Edit : mapping not modifier

Comment: `RestrictedFromDividend` in your code looks like a `mapping`, not a `modifier`! And no, you can't do that. You'll have to add a function which does that, and call it from the outside. The function can be "automated" to a certain degree, but you'd still have to invoke it explicitly from the off-chain. For example, it can check that a certain amount of time has elapsed since `RestrictedFromDividend[msg.sender]` has been set to `true`, and decide whether or not it should be set back to `false`, according to that.

Answer (score 1):

You can create modifier which will compare current block.timestamp with time you want, and then depending on case, it will allow/dissallow whatever has to be done after that.

Or instead of saving this:

> **RestrictedFromDividend[msg.sender] = true;**

you can store it like this

> **RestrictedFromDividendUntil[msg.sender] = {some time you want};**
>
> And than again add modifier/function which will based on current time,
>   return true/false after comparing
>   **RestrictedFromDividendUntil[msg.sender]** and **block.timestamp**

```
Example: 
modifier onlyIfNotRestricted {
 require (block.timestamp <= RestrictedFromDividendUntil[msg.sender]);
 _;
}
```

or

```
Example:
function isRestricted() public view returns (bool) {
 if(block.timestamp <= RestrictedFromDividendUntil[msg.sender]) return true;
 return false;
}
```